# Implementing row based access based on role

Tags: laravel

I have created a table that contains Ticket information, with an id, message body, user id and department id.

I would like to be able to limit access to these tickets, such that only users from the corresponding department can access the relevant tickets, and can not view other department's tickets.

I have attempted to make an updatable view for each department and granting select on this, but it does not work very well.

Is there a simple way to achieve this kind of role based access?

Comment: "*Is there a simple way [...]*" - Not really, no. You'd need to cross-reference the applied roles to the currently authenticated user via Middleware, and limit all `Ticket::` queries to only show the same department(s). Have you tried anything? Are you using Laravel's built in `Auth` system or something else (Sentinel, Spatie, etc)?

Comment: I am using the built-in Auth system to create the admin role. I haven't tried anything other than trying to limit the access from the MySQL side.